# Anchor tag not works in IE6

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6

I am using

```
<a href="www.google.com" > test link </a>
```

I didn't understand why its not working in IE6.

Comment: The whitespace after the `href`-attrbute could be causing trouble. Try writing it as @BoltClock posted.

Comment: I know an alternative to one of the answers below, but you never accept them so whats the point...

Answer (score 10):

You need to include `http://`.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"> test link </a>
```

You should also explain what exactly you mean by 'not working', but regardless of that, that's the only mistake I see in your link.